# Spring Rest Controller PUT method request body validation?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

Here is what i have in my controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/accountholders/{cardHolderId}/cards/{cardId}", produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8", consumes = "application/json", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@ResponseBody
public CardVO putCard(@PathVariable("cardHolderId") final String cardHolderId,
        @PathVariable("cardId") final String cardId, @RequestBody final RequestVO requestVO) {
    if (!Pattern.matches("\\d+", cardHolderId) || !Pattern.matches("\\d+", cardId)) {
        throw new InvalidDataFormatException();
    }
    final String requestTimeStamp = DateUtil.getUTCDate();
    iCardService.updateCardInfo(cardId, requestVO.isActive());
    final CardVO jsonObj = iCardService.getCardHolderCardInfo(cardHolderId, cardId, requestTimeStamp);
    return jsonObj;
}
```

This is the request body bean:-

```
public class RequestVO {

    private boolean active;

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }
```

The issue that I am having is when i sent the request body as 
{"acttttt":true} the active is set to false it updates the cardinfo with false. Whatever wrong key value i sent the active is considered as false. How would I handle this is their a way. Every other scenario is handled by spring with a 404.

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the default value for primitive `boolean` is `false`. Use its corresponding Wrapper, `Boolean`, instead:

```
public class RequestVO {

    private Boolean active;

    // getters and setters
}
```

If the `active` value is required, you can also add validation annotations like `NotNull`:

```
public class RequestVO {

    @NotNull
    private Boolean active;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Then use `Valid` annotation paired with `RequestBody` annotation to trigger automatic validation process.

Comment: Another issue that I am having now is the when i sent {"active":2343} its taking it as true I think its considering 0 as false and everything else as true is their a way to check resolve that not to consider that.

Comment: I guess you could write your own [`Converter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/converter/Converter.html) and add it to list of converters.